# NSNumberFormatter currency remove trailing zeros

Tags: objective-c, currency, nsnumberformatter

I want to format prices like 45.50 but I don't want prices like 45.00. How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 4):

I did it this way:

```
NSNumber *amount = @(50.5);
NSNumberFormatter *currencyFormat = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[currencyFormat setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
[currencyFormat setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];

if (trunc(amount.floatValue) == amount.floatValue) {
    [currencyFormat setMaximumFractionDigits:0];
} else {
    [currencyFormat setMaximumFractionDigits:2];
}

NSLog(@"%@", [currencyFormat stringFromNumber:amount]);
```

I like this solution for its simplicity. Output will be `$50.50`. And for `amount = @(50.0)` will be `$50`

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
[formatter setMaximumFractionDigits:2];
[formatter setRoundingMode: NSNumberFormatterRoundUp];
NSString *numberString = [formatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:22.368511]];
NSLog(@"Result...%@",numberString);//Result 22.37
```

Now trail unwanted like this:

```
NSString* CWDoubleToStringWithMax2Decimals(double d) {
 NSString* s = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", d];
 NSCharacterSet* cs = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharacterInString:@"0."];
 NSRange r = [s rangeOfCharacterInSet:cs
                             options:NSBackwardsSearch | NSAnchoredSearch];
 if (r.location != NSNotFound) {
  s = [s substringToIndex:r.location];
 }
 return s;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're just after a very quick and dirty hack . . .

```
// Get the price as a string
NSString *priceString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%2.2f", priceFloat];

// Trim if needed
if ([priceString hasSuffix:@".00"])
    priceString = [priceString substringToIndex:priceString.length-3];
```

---

NB This method won't work for localised content i.e. In Europe the decimal separator is a comma so you will see 45,00, not 45.00.

Answer (score 0):

```
float myOriginalPrice = 45.50;
    CGFloat mod = fmod(myOriginalPrice, 1);
    if (mod == 0){
        mod = (int)myOriginalPrice;
        NSLog(@"%.0f", mod);


    } else {
         NSLog(@"%f", myOriginalPrice);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  INPUT : 12.74 OR 12.745

NSString *inputString=[NSString string];


inputString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.4g",12.74f];


NSLog(@"inputString : %@ \n\n",inputString);
```

OUTPUT:

```
  inputString : 12.74 
INPUT : 12.00 OR 12.000

  NSString *inputString=[NSString string];


 inputString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.4g",12.00f];


 NSLog(@"inputString : %@ \n\n",inputString);
```

OUTPUT:

inputString : 12 
UPDATED ANSWER: for his comment question

INPUT:12.30

i assume here he is going to show this value in some UI like UILabel,.....Not For Calculation.

```
 NSString *inputString=[NSString string];


 inputString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.4g",12.30f];


 NSArray *arr=[inputString componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];


 if ([arr count] >= 2) {

    NSString *secondStr=[arr objectAtIndex:1];

if ([secondStr length]<2) {

    inputString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@0",inputString];
}
}
```

NSLog(@"inputString : %@ \n\n",inputString);
OUTPUT:

inputString : 12.30